# Apex Trigger to Sync Accounts and Contacts with same Email

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'll start off by saying I'm a complete noob to Salesforce and Apex Triggers.

What we've done so far is added a custom Email field to the Account Record.  Account records are automatically created via external integration (magento store customers).

We also have Contact records that are created automatically from a different external integration (zendesk).

What we want to happen is when a new Account is created, all of the Account information will be transferred onto the the Contact record if a record exists with the same email, if a Contact doesn't exist, it will create a New Contact with all of the same Account information.

I'm thinking this needs to be done with some sort of **upsert** trigger whenever a new Account is created / updated?

EDIT, here is the current trigger I'm using:

```
trigger UpsertTrigger on Account (after insert, after update) {

List<String> listAccountEmails = new List<Account>();
//capture all the account email updated
for( Account a : Trigger.new )
  {
     listAccountEmails.add(String.Valueof(a.Email));
  }

//Get all the related contacts match email address
List<Contact> listContacts = new List<Contact>();
listContacts = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email in :listAccountEmails];

//Convert list Contacts into map with email as key
Map<String, Contact> mapContacts = Map<>(String, Contact);
for ( Contact c : listContacts)
   mapContacts.put(c.Email, c);

// Loop thru account emails and create contact record if email doesnot exist or //update contact if exist
 for (String e : listAccountEmails) {
    if (mapContacts.isContainsKey(e) == true) { 
//Map Account fields to Contact fields

              a.Last_Name__c = c.LastName,
              a.First_Name__c = c.FirstName,
              a.Magento_Customer_ID__c = c.Magento_Customer_ID__c,
              a.Sales_Rep__c = c.Sales_Rep__c,
              a.id = c.AccountId,
              a.Email__c = c.Email) 
      }
else
//Create New Contact

    Contact con = new Contact();

    con.LastName = a.Last_Name__c;
    con.FirstName = a.First_Name__c;
    con.Magento_Customer_ID__c = a.Magento_Customer_ID__c;
    con.Email = a.Email__c;
    con.Sales_Rep__c = a.Sales_Rep__c;
    con.AccountId = a.id;

    insert con; 
}

upsert Contacts;
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't have any upsert type of trigger separately. Upsert performs two things. 1. Insert if the record is not there. 2. Update the record if it is existing.

For this specific requirement, you need to write a trigger on Account Object as below.

```
trigger UpsertTrigger on Account (after insert, after update) {

List<String> listAccountEmails = new List<Account>();
//capture all the account email updated
for( Account a : Trigger.new )
  {
     listAccountEmails.add(String.Valueof(a.Email));
  }

//Get all the related contacts match email address
List<Contact> listContacts = new List<Contact>();
listContacts = [SELECT Id, FistName, LastName, Email, and other fields FROM Contact WHERE Email in :listAccountEmails];

//Convert list Contacts into map with email as key
Map<String, Contact> mapContacts = Map<>(String, Contact);
for ( Contact c : listContacts)
   mapContacts.put(c.Email, c);

// Loop thru account emails and create contact record if email doesnot exist or //update contact if exist
for (String e : listAccountEmails) {
    if (mapContacts.isContainsKey(e) == true) { 
                  Map the account fields to contact fields 
          }
    else
       Create contact records 
}

upsert Contacts;
```

Comment: Looks like I'm running into a compile error  **Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'Map' at line 15 column 35**  I've updated my original question with updated trigger using your code, any idea?